# HTML5 offline appcache: Force refresh of all content?

Tags: html, offline-caching, html5-appcache

My small HTML5 app needs to be re-deployed on a server. I understood I only had to touch the .appcache file to have every browser update to the last version of the files upon next visit.

The manifest looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Version: 201209251353

index.html
apple-touch-icon.png
css/styles.css
data/dump.bin
img/background.png
img/sprites.png
js/core.js
js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js
vid/walkthrough.mov
```

To "touch", I added a comment (#Version:) which I mean to be updated any time the content changes.

Strangely, some files are updated. Not all, for isntance, a colleague gets the latest core.js, but still displays an old walkthrough.mov.

Is there a simple mechanism to force update all files from the cache?

I found the following code on SO and included it in the scripts, expecting it to help. Not sure how needful it is :(

```
    // Application cache refresh
    window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

      window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
        if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
          // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
          // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
          window.applicationCache.swapCache();
          if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        } else {
          // Manifest didn't changed. Nothing new to server.
        }
      }, false);

    }, false);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What [expiry headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) are you setting on your manifest and content?

If you've set (for example) the expiry on `vid/walkthrough.mov` to be one month in the future and that file is small enough to go in the *browser* cache (note: not the *application* cache) then the browser will refresh the application cache from the version in the browser cache rather than requesting it across the network again (if it's less than a month since it fetched the file).

If you've set a future expiry date on the manifest file then in some versions of some browsers this can cause an updated manifest not to be detected.

Comment: Thanks! So is it good enough to just set the `Expires` header to 1994 on all files in the appcache? It will still be available offline?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, that I am using, but is not pretty is to rename the appcache file. Then all content will be refreshed as the appcache will be lost.